# google adsense is not working in wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, adsense

I have one issue regarding google adsense. My website is in Gujarati Language and I try to put Google Adsense in my site http://medha-pandya-bhatt.in/, but some how it throw the 403 error.

[image]

I have done verification from Google Adsense.

Can anyone help me for that error.

Answer (score 0):

1- do you use plugin for placing AdSense?
2- Did you add the code snippet that google gave you to the header of your website?
3- do you have an active AD blocker?
4- I need the URL for further answar
Regards

Comment: Thanks for reply, here is my comments:
1- No.
2- Yes, you can see that code in my site. http://medha-pandya-bhatt.in/
3- In website or in browser?
4- http://medha-pandya-bhatt.in/

Comment: Hello, 
Have you added your website to your Adsense account (Now go to Adsense account, Click the Gear icon -> Settings -> My sites -> Manage sites  and add your website. Click the three dots icon and select authorization and check if ” Only Authorize my verified sites to use my ad code” is  off.)

Comment: I have attached error message in image, please have a look into it and let me guide